# Problem on sylow theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Consider $U$ is a normal subgroup of p-sylow group of $P$. Now can it be proven that normalizer of $U$ will contain only $P$ as it's sylow group. I am trying to prove by contradiction. But so far got nowhere. Is this problem even true, any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: No that is not true. It is possible that $U$ is normal in the whole group. $U$ could be a direct factor of $G$ for example.

Comment: Can u give an example contradicting this please

Comment: I explained how to find examples in my comment.

Answer (score 2):

Take $U=1$ as normal subgroup of one of the three Sylow $2$-subgroup of $S_3$ and you have a counterexample.